# how i still keep my data even my app offline

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How can I still be able to see the contents of my chat with other users even when I’m offline? like whatsapp i can still see my chat history even offline. and using cloud firestore. thanks!

Comment: Firestore has offline queries, and they're enabled by default for Android and iOS.  Is that not working for you?

Comment: I don't know why I have to reload it first and then it can display data from streambuilder. how do I save data from firestore so that I can still see data even though my application is offline.

Comment: and I also tried to extract data from Firestore and save it in a list and make it inside initState () but the data in the list is not called how do I finish this? thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore has offline support by default but it does not support `await` and `runTransaction` in offline mode. If these are present then the future will not be resolved, making it look like that `Firestore` is not supporting offline mode. Just write your code without any `await` calls or `runTransaction` and you should find that your app supports offline mode.

For example, in [this section of code](https://gist.github.com/jrhml05/eb1a1df5c9a3a53514522601394b8dec#file-addhouseholder-dart-L146) will not support offline mode because you are `await`-ing for the future to be resolved. Instead, removing the `await` keyword will result in updating the list in offline mode and when internet comes back then the database is also updated.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. thanks for the info. and by the way I forgot to use setState () so it needed to reload again to get the data.

Comment: Hi @BonaBerto if the question has been resolved don't forget to mark the resolved answer. Thanks